# Save Checkbox Preference value in custom SharedPreferences file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

When we are using **CheckBoxPreference** in android preference, after we check/uncheck CheckBox, value (true/false) is save in default shared preferences file.

In my application, i'm using my own shared preferences file. So, i need to save **CheckBoxPreference** value in my own shared preferences file instead of saving in default shared preferences file.

I can save **CheckBoxPreference** value in my own shared preferences file with `setOnPreferenceChangeListener`. But i need to avoid saving it in default shared preferences file.

How could i achieve this ?

Comment: You can't. For this purpose you need to design your custom layout and use CheckBox. You need Fragment or Activity instead of Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) as a separate helper class and set up the check boxes. This way you will have flexibility in your app and in your workflow. This way you could give settings your own custom layout. For reference, here is a sample [app](https://github.com/rakeeb11/simple-shared-preferences). Hope this helps :)